# Angular package build generates if(false) {...} blocks

Tags: angular

I have an Angular package repository on GitHub, https://github.com/marcobuschini/parking-widget, that tests all green, and builds with no errors with `ng build`. Unfortunately, the generated code includes some `if (false) {...}` statements around properties the module should export. Therefore the module does not work. I know that it is a configuration option gone wild. But by reading the [APF v9.0](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview) documentation I cannot figure out which option is wrong or missing.

Any ideas on how to further investigate the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating `angularCompilerOptions` in `parking-widget/projects/widget/tsconfig.lib.json` to match what is written in the APF 9.0 documentation mentioned in the question the `if (false)` statements disappeared.

The widget didn't work yet.

After further investigation, I found out that the widget didn't export itself. So I added an `exports: [WidgetComponent]` to the `@NgModule` section of the `widget.module.ts` file.